# Select position of the labeled axes in Plot3D or Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

In a 3D plot, there are 4 possible positions (frame edges) for the ticks/labels for each of the axes (x,y,z). Is there any way to specify which position is selected, independent of the view angle? Here is an example:

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Ticks -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Here, the x axis labels are on the bottom-left frame edge. In the following image, it is on the top-right frame edge.

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Ticks -> Automatic, Axes -> True, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.0, 2.}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

I want to select the edge independent of my view angle choice. Is that possible?

Comment: I feel certain this is a duplicate but a search turned up nothing. Does this seem familiar to anyone else? *Never mind, I found it.*

Comment: Thanks, I also felt this must be a duplicate but failed to find the other post.

Comment: Fortunately your post will serve to enrich the search engine for other users.